# How to get latest documents from FaunaDB, based on timestamp?

Tags: javascript, faunadb

Currently I store some data in FaunaDB every week. This is done using a cronjob. In my code I'm trying to fetch the documents from only the last two weeks. I'd like to use the timestamp to do so.

**One of the documents to fetch:**

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("weeklyContributors"), "350395411XXXXXXXX"),
  "ts": 1670421954340000,
  "data": {
     ...allMyDataFields
  }
}
```

**My code**

```
const now = Date.now() * 1000;
const twoWeeksAgo = (Date.now() - 12096e5) * 1000;

console.log(now); //returns 1670493608804000
console.log(twoWeeksAgo); // returns 1669284008804000

// the stored document has a timestamp of 1670421954340000, so this should be in between [now] and [twoWeeksAgo]

await client.query(
      q.Paginate(
        q.Range(
          q.Match(q.Index("get_weekly_list_by_ts")),
          twoWeeksAgo,
          now
        )
      )
    );
```

[This is a screenshot of the index I created in Fauna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGxci.png)

Above code should fetch all documents where the timestamp's between `now` and `twoWeeksAgo` but it returns an empty array (so no documents match the query). Above code doesn't generate any errors, it does return a statuscode 200, so syntax should be fine. Why can't I fetch the document I gave in this example?

**UPDATE**

Found the solution for the index. The index should filter on `Values`, not `Terms`. Enter `TS` and `Ref` returns the document. BUt now I don't know how to get the corresponding document.

This returns an error

```
await client.query(
      q.Map(
        q.Paginate(
          q.Range(
            q.Match(q.Index("get_weekly_list_by_ts")),
            twoWeeksAgo,
            now
          )
        ),

        q.Lambda((x) => q.Get(x))
      )
    );
```

[Changed index screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqGr1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on figuring out most of the answer for yourself!

As you deduced, the `terms` definition in an index specifies the fields to search for, and the `values` definition specifies the field values to return for matching entries.

Since you added the document reference to the `values` definition, all that you need now is to fetch that document. To do that, you need to `Map` over the results.

The following example uses Shell syntax, and involves sample documents that I created with a `createdAt` field recording the creation timestamp (since `ts` is the last-modified timestamp):

```
> Map(
  Paginate(
    Range(
      Match(Index("get_weekly_list_by_ts")),
      TimeSubtract(Now(), 14, "days"),
      Now()
    )
  ),
  Lambda(
    ["ts", "ref"],
    Get(Var("ref"))
  )
)
{
  data: [
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("weeklyContributors"), "350498857823502848"),
      ts: 1670520608640000,
      data: { createdAt: Time("2022-12-01T17:30:08.633Z"), name: 'Fourth' }
    },
    {
      ref: Ref(Collection("weeklyContributors"), "350498864657072640"),
      ts: 1670520615160000,
      data: { createdAt: Time("2022-12-07T17:30:15.152Z"), name: 'Fifth' }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since your index returns `ts` and `ref`, notice that the `Lambda` function accepts both parameters in an array. The `Lambda` parameters have to match the number returned by the index. Then the `Lambda` calls `Get` to fetch the document.

In case you're wondering, here's the index definition that I used for my example:

```
> Get(Index("get_weekly_list_by_ts"))
{
  ref: Index("get_weekly_list_by_ts"),
  ts: 1670520331720000,
  active: true,
  serialized: true,
  name: 'get_weekly_list_by_ts',
  source: Collection("weeklyContributors"),
  values: [ { field: [ 'data', 'createdAt' ] }, { field: [ 'ref' ] } ],
  partitions: 8
}
```

My index is misnamed: I used the same name from your original query to help you correlate what is being used.

Note: there is no need to mask the document ID in a document that you share. It is only valid for the database containing the document.

Comment: Definitely worthfull response, thank you!